# AirPlay with just iPhone and Apple TV

Tags: wifi, appletv, airplay

Can I stream things from an iPhone to an Apple TV with no additional equipment (i.e. no wireless router)? Will they be able to talk to each-other just like that (like Lion Mac Books apparently can for Air Drop), or do I need to also set up a WiFi network?

Assuming latest versions of all devices and software.

Comment: Now this is just a guess at something that might work, but if you are jailbroken, you may be able to create an ad-hoc network from your phone and connect the Apple TV directly to it. In theory anyway.

Answer (score 2):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3737223?start=0&tstart=0

So basically you don't need an internet connection, but both your iPhone and Apple TV will have to be in the same network.

So to answer you're question, yes, you'll have to setup a WiFi (LAN) network. (or ethernet)

Comment: Thanks. Ethernet won't do, though, right? Cannot hook the iPhone into it, I believe.

Comment: You can always hook up your mac to Apple TV and create a local network from your mac. For iPhone it's only possible with WiFi